# Do position/momentum/energy correlation violate the Bell inequalities just like spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, thought-experiment, bells-inequality

The descriptions of Bell's Theorem that I've read specifically refer to the example of correlation between spin or polarization of two particles that were released from a common origin, like an atomic nucleus, where it is known they have opposite spins due to the process that created them.

Do the correlations predicted by quantum theory for continuous variables like position, energy, and momentum, also violate the Bell inequalities?  If so, can you give an example of a simple thought/real experiment that demonstrates this? (preferably involving only two particles, and especially for the position variable, if possible, since position is just easier to visualize)

Comment: Since Bell inequality violation comes directly from the basic rules of quantum mechanics, it can be realized in principle with any set of observables. (Every time a derivation says "spin $x$", just mentally replace it with "position near point $x$".) The focus on spin/polarization is just because (1) its inherent discreteness makes the math easier and more importantly, (2) it's much easier to make Bell pairs for spin/polarization in the lab, than for the other observables.

Comment: @knzhou  Okay... so if a real experiment would be infeasible, can you describe a thought experiment for position measurement with two particles to demonstrate the violation?

Comment: It's literally the exact same thing as the spin case, only the letters change. For example, let $|a \rangle$ and $|b \rangle$ be position eigenstates meaning "an electron is at position $a$ or $b$, respectively", and similarly define $|A \rangle$ and $|B \rangle$ for some other particle, like a proton. Then prepare the Bell pair state $|a A \rangle - |b B \rangle$ (this is the part that is hard to do in the lab) and continue with the derivation as usual.

Comment: The part which is unintuitive is that at some point, you need to make "nondiagonal" position measurements, which are the analogue of diagonal spin measurements, which project onto states like $|a \rangle \pm |b \rangle$. This is even harder to realize in the lab, but it's completely allowed by the laws of quantum mechanics. Maybe this is where your intuition that spin and position are different comes from.

Comment: @knzhou  Maybe I don't quite have the background for this discussion.  You mean Bell's derivation in [his original paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/111654/files/vol1p195-200_001.pdf)?  It's not too easy for me to follow, but doesn't it explicitly assume the variable is spin, since it includes the unit vector representing detector orientation?  Also, what does a nondiagonal position measurement even mean?  You're measuring whether the system is in a particular superposition?  Isn't that impossible, since the measurement collapses it to one position or the other?

Comment: @knzhou  I mean, position eigenstates are not superpositions of each other, the way spin states are ... right?

Comment: Just a reminder: the original argument that led Bell to his inequalities is that of EPR. In that argument, two entangled particles are sent apart and measurements of momentum/position are performed on the particles. All, you'd have to do is reformulate Bell's argument for that case.

Comment: @Raskolnikov  Can you help me with the conceptual part of formulating it?  In the spin case, we can say that measuring particle $a$ to be, say, spin up along $+x$ causes particle $b$ to act as though it had been $-x$ the whole time, based on its distribution over possible measurement axes.  So the need for non-locality is obvious.  Is there an analogous statement for position?

Comment: Given the discussion above, I think a far more productive avenue would be for you to write up how you think the proof of Bell's theorem works for the spin case, in terms of explicit equations. (After all, understanding this is an absolutely necessary prerequisite to discussing anything about local realism at all.) Then write down the analogous equations with positions instead of spins, and tell us the point where you think the analogy breaks down. Otherwise we'll be talking in circles indefinitely.

Comment: The article ["A Bell inequality involving position, momentum and energy"](https://ur.booksc.me/book/2990682/d2b618) does what you ask for.